# Why From resets to 0?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I am learning Animations in WPF. So, I decided to create an Analogue Clock. For designing the second Hand of an analogue clock I used Line element of WPF.

Now I want to rotate it by 6 degrees from its current position each second. So I used a Simple DoubleAnimation like below:

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="secondHandRotateTransform" 
                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                 By="6" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="0:0:1"/>
```

The above mentioned code works perfectly for first second. It rotates the line by 6 degrees. As I have set the RepeatBehavior to Forever I expect it to continue forever. The animation continues forever but I expect the `From` value of this animation to be changed to the last value returned by the animation. But I get the `From`=0 everytime the animation is repeated.

Why `From` resets to 0 ? Is there any property on DoubleAnimation that stores the last value returned by the animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, got answer from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746678(v=vs.110).aspx) link.

I need to set `IsCumulative="True"`

So, now my code looks like :

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="secondHandRotateTransform" 
                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                 IsCumulative="True"
                 By="6" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="0:0:1"/>
```